# Is this possible to extract an Object from nested array through mongoDB Query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema in mongoose.

```
var AttendanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ownerId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  companyId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  months: [
    {
      currentSalary: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      },
      month: {
        type: Date,
      },
      salary: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      }
      days: [
        {
          manuallyUpdated: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
          },
          date: {
            type: Date,
          },
          perDaySalary: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          status: {
            type: String,
          }
        }
      ]

    }
  ]
});
```

I want to extract the the single object in days array.

**Note:** There is days array nested in months array and i have used $pull to pull out that day but i want to pull and push again (updated day).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this if you know at which element inside days array there is information you need because days array will consist of multiple elements.
suppose that you need it from 1st element inside array:

```
Attendance.findOne({_id: request.id}, function(err, foundAttendance){
console.log(foundAttendance.days[0].date);
}
```

and you can change 0 to any number you want according to data you need.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question